# Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. But I do have it

Tags: python, pip, visual-studio-2017, anaconda, visual-c++

I am attempting to install a Python package. In the directory containing the `setup.py` file I create an Anaconda environment (as suggested in the package documentation), and then I type the command `pip install .`

Loads of other required packages are downloaded and installed. So far everything goes fine, but when it comes to the installation of `cytoolz` (I am not convinced it is an actual package installation -- I think it may be a set of setup tools), the following error occurs:

```
building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I followed the instructions (I had previously installed Visual Studio 2017 on my computer, but back in the days I only needed the .NET desktop dev. module), and I installed the "Desktop dev. with C++" module, as recommended in other posts. As confirmation, in the list of installed programs, I see the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (that is version 14.13.26020), but when repeating the package installation procedure as explained above, the same error pops up again.

What should I do to fix this?

It could perhaps be that I have version 14.13 and the package in question requires the 14.0 one?

**EDIT**: I don't know whether this information can help: I have installed both Visual Studio Community 2017 and Visual Studio Build Tools 2017, and in both the proper C++ dev. module has been installed.

Comment: Relevant: [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2017_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29).  Edit your question to indicate what Python package your attempting to install.  [Cytoolz](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/issues/126) is all sorts of broken.